# Rails 4 Select Dropdown for all Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement a select dropdown that displays a selection of model attribute names. This also includes the names of associated model attributes in some case.

I have tried using Model.attribute_names, but this also adds in id, created_at and updated_at attributes. Associated attributes also needs to be displayed in a user friendly fashion i.e. account_id needs to map to account.number.

I am trying to do this for quite a few models and I want to add all attributes into one select dropdown. Another tutorial indicated that Model.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name) returns all associative models, so I was wondering if looping through these might be a solution?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`column_names`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class):

```
Model.column_names # will return an array of table attributes
```

## EDIT

As to remove unnecessary attributes from the selection list, you can create a constant, which defines all attributes you don't want to be in your select list:

```
REMOVE_FROM_LIST = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'id']
```

and then calling `Model.column_names - REMOVE_FROM_LIST` will return only desired attributes.

You can go further and define a class method, returning desired list of attributes:

```
def self.desired_list_of_attributes
  Model.column_names - REMOVE_FROM_LIST
end
```

Now, calling `Model.desired_list_of_attributes` returns a list with only needed attributes.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. The Model.column_names solution does provide all the attribute names for a specific model. Do you perhaps know how to remove unwanted attributes as well as display associated attributes in the same array? Since I'm using rails 4 I don't think that accessible_attributes will work for me...I might be wrong since I'm quite new to Rails.

Comment: @Herm you can use any methods available for `Array`, for instance, `Array#reject` - `Model.column_names.reject{|c| c.include? 'created_at'}`

Answer (score 1):

I would move this into a concern:

**model/concerns/attr_getter.rb**

```
module AttrGetter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  module ClassMethods
    def accessible_attrs
      column_names.reject { |a| a.in? %w(id created_at updated_at) }
    end
  end
end
```

And then `include` this in whatever models you need.

As for getting association attributes, I would just include them specifically in your views by adding whatever models' attribute arrays together.

Comment: just opened a question, cause was going to mention concerns, if OP needs such functionality more, then once. Good point!

Comment: I just had to add extend ActiveSupport::Concern in the second line to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: Ah yeah. Updated answer. It's a group effort!